# Specify icon/ image in "Recently Viewed" tab in iOS Chrome

Tags: ios, google-chrome, favicon

How can I specify the icon/ image thumbnail and text used in the iOS Chrome new tab? It doesn't appear to be http://example.com/favicon.ico.

[Screenshot of iOS Chrome new tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYWsg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick and easy solution**

Apparently you have only one icon, `favicon.ico`, which is mostly ignored by mobile browsers. You should at least define a Touch icon. You can use a service such as [Real Favicon Generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net) to create everything and support all browsers.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

**Precise (but probably too elaborate) solution**

Run the [compatibility test](http://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test) to understand which icon is actually displayed by Chrome in this particular place. For example, if you discover that Chrome takes the 152x152 Apple Touch icon, well, now you know what you need.

Problem: you probably want to support all scenarios (Android Chrome, iOS Safari, etc.), not only the "New tab" of iOS Chrome. So even if you find out, you will probably want to declare other icons.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had most of the Apple icon files/ browserconfig.xml etc, but have added the missing ones specified in the link.